# Do PostgreSQL query plans depend on table row count?

Tags: performance, postgresql, explain, sql-execution-plan

My users table doesn't have many rows... yet.

Might the query plan of the same query change as the table grows?

I.e., to see how my application will scale, should I seed my `users` table with BILLIONS  of rows before using `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Yes, the plan **will** change as the number of rows increases.

Comment: K. Thank you. Hmm... Next, I will find a good way to seed my users table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estimated row counts are probably the most important factor that influence which query plan is chosen.

Two examples that support this:

- If you use a `WHERE` condition on an indexed column of a table, three things can happen:

  1. If the table is very small or a high percentage of the rows match the condition, a sequential scan will be used to read the whole table and filter out the rows that match the condition.
  2. If the table is large and a low percentage of the rows match the condition, an index scan will be used.
  3. If the table is large and a medium percentage of rows match the condition, a bitmap index scan will be used.
- If you join two tables, the estimated row counts on the tables will determine if a nested loop join is chosen or not.